# invalid digit "9" in octal constant arduino

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Estou com um problema na minha função para medir temperatura.

```
#include "max6675.h"

int ktcSO = 8;
int ktcCS = 9;
int ktcCLK = 10;

MAX6675 ktc(ktcCLK, ktcCS, ktcSO);


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() 
{
   Serial.print("Temperatura = "); 
   Serial.println((1,11679312453725*ktc.readCelsius())+(-0,00531623949317312*ktc.readCelsius()*ktc.readCelsius())+(0,0000975327598421513*ktc.readCelsius()*ktc.readCelsius()*ktc.readCelsius())+(-0,000000653954749797908*ktc.readCelsius()*ktc.readCelsius()*ktc.readCelsius()*ktc.readCelsius())-1,63915244051268);
   delay(1000);
}
```

Ela me retorna o erro: `invalid digit "9" in octal constant` que parte da minha `Serial.println`. Como resolvo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Arduino utiliza as linguagens de programação C/C++ e, na sintaxe delas, um número float é definido utilizando ponto, e não vírgula. Por exemplo:

```
float pi_correto = 3.14 /* correto */
float pi_errado = 3,14 /* incorreto */
```

Você está recebendo essa mensagem de erro porque um número que começa com 0 é interpretado pelo compilador como um número na base 8 (ou seja, um número octal).

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!